# is there anyway to open href links in message box?

Tags: javascript

i want to open html href link files in message box or any display box.( sorry i dont know, exact word for box.)

is there any way to open href links in any kind of display boxes.? i need answer only in JavaScript technology. Help me

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer? You want to display HTML in the dialog or you want to have clickable links in the dialog? What kind of dialog, the alert box or some type of modal?

Comment: For whatever reason you want this dosent seem right approach. I would suggest you go for some of the JQuery Popus instead.

Comment: Do you know what it looks like? Can you include an image or a link to one?

Comment: @DustinDavis i have `hello.html` in `files` folder. and i have `html` code with `<a href="files/hello.html">Hello file</a>`. Normally this will be displayed in normal window. I dont want that. I want to display this `hello.html` in dialog box like [this](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Comment: @GuruKara i have `hello.html` in `files` folder. and i have `html` code with `<a href="files/hello.html">Hello file</a>`. Normally this will be displayed in normal window. I dont want that. I want to display this `hello.html` in dialog box like [this](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Comment: @putvande i have `hello.html` in `files` folder. and i have `html` code with `<a href="files/hello.html">Hello file</a>`. Normally this will be displayed in normal window. I dont want that. I want to display this `hello.html` in dialog box like [this](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Comment: Try the method listed in this link http://forum.jquery.com/topic/loading-existing-html-pages-into-a-jquery-dialog-window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think an `alert()` or `confirm()` or any other built-in browser dialog box can display more than just simple text.  But you can have any HTML content you want in a modal `div` dialog.  The [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) is a popular example.  You don't need to use that plugin, though it would make it easy.

Essentially you just render a hidden element to the page (commonly a `div`) and respond to some page event by styling the element to "float" over the rest of the page.  That element, since it's part of the DOM like anything else, can contain any HTML you'd like.

Comment: its quite interesting. but [here](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) i can only able to display some statements but not html files. i need to display html files. help me out pls

Comment: @user2655873: Perhaps I misunderstood the question. I thought you wanted to display HTML content in a dialog box. You want to actually have a link open a new window? If you do want to use the jQuery UI dialog then its content can be an `iframe` to the other HTML document. However, a much simpler approach could just be to have your link open to a new window. This has nothing to do with JavaScript and is achieved simply by the `target` attribute on the link, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a Or, using JavaScript, you can call `window.open()` to a new page.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at jQuery's fancybox -> [Fancy Box](http://fancybox.net/)

Answer (score 0):

well depending on how you building your web app. You could integrate twitter bootstrap, it has tons of great JavaScript plugins. a modal might solve your problem.

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals

Alternative you can uses a lightbox, I see someone has already mentioned fancybox. The second version is now out.

its supports images, iframe, and divs as conetent
http://fancyapps.com/